# What is relation between dv/dt with rate of change in speed?

Tags: kinematics

What is relation between dv/dt  with rate of change in speed?

Comment: Do you mean speed or velocity?

Answer (score 3):

If v means speed, dv/dt is called rate of change of speed w.r.t time. But if you mean v by velocity then, rate of change of speed w.r.t time would be $\frac {d} {dt}$|v|.